# Need Addon help fixing Name Detection in Chat

Tags: lua, add-on, world-of-warcraft

The following code is suppose to change a user name say Player in any text example: '[Player2]: Hi Player' into '[Player2]: Hi >Player<' with Player in red and >< symbols in yellow. Problem is its not detecting other players saying it and is just plain coloring them by class and warning when I say my name when it should be the other way around.

I understand there is likely Global Leaks and such as this is a beta phase addon at the moment and I am constantly working on rewriting functions to make them better but for now I am trying to get everything working first. If you can simplify the Name detection and change it without messing with links in WoW I would take the advice and I will throw a comment line in the code to show your name for credit and in the main addon page. Otherwise I just need the fix to find out why its not working as intended.

Here is the code:

```
    local _PlayerName2 = CM2.StripSpecial(UnitName("player"), true)
    _PlayerName2 = _PlayerName2:lower()
    local _PlayerName, _ = UnitName("player")

    --Detect if the current character said their own name. Block Warnings.
    local throwWarn = true

    if ChatAuthor == curPlayer then
        --Player said something.
        throwWarn = false
        --CM2.Print("Disabled Warnings")
    end

    if text == nil then
        print("Text Nil, Check URL Detection Code")
    end

    --Color own name in your chat. Really only sender name because all other references will
    --be tied to the alert.     
    if throwWarn == false and text:find(" "..curPlayer.." ") ~= nil then
        text = CM2.far(text, curPlayer, CM2.ColorName(CM2_Nick[plainPlayerName][2], plainPlayerName))
    end
    if throwWarn == false and text:find(case_insensitive_pattern(plainPlayerName)) ~= nil then
        text = CM2.far(text, plainPlayerName, CM2.ColorName(CM2_Nick[plainPlayerName][2], plainPlayerName))
    end

    --Detect and alert when playername is spoken
    local pos = 0

    if throwWarn == true and text:find(" ".._PlayerName.." ") ~= nil then
        --Detect if the Original Player name was said.
        text = text:gsub(" ".._PlayerName.." ", " "..CHATMOD_COLOR["YELLOW"]..">"..CHATMOD_COLOR["RED"].._PlayerName..CHATMOD_COLOR["YELLOW"].."<\124r ")           
        UIErrorsFrame:AddMessage(text, red, green, blue, nil, UIERRORS_HOLD_TIME)
        PlaySound("FriendJoinGame")
    elseif throwWarn == true and text:find(" "..case_insensitive_pattern(plainPlayerName).." ") ~= nil then
        --Detect if the stripped down Player Name was said.
        text = text:gsub(" ".._PlayerName2.." ", " "..CHATMOD_COLOR["YELLOW"]..">"..CHATMOD_COLOR["RED"].._PlayerName2..CHATMOD_COLOR["YELLOW"].."<\124r ")         
        UIErrorsFrame:AddMessage(text, red, green, blue, nil, UIERRORS_HOLD_TIME)
        PlaySound("FriendJoinGame")
    end



    if text == nil then
        print("Text Nil, Check playername highlighter Code")
    end


    -- Color Nicks
    if CM2_Options["ColorNicks"] then
        -- Hold Original unmodified words for later use
        temp2 = text
        temp2 = CM2.StripSpecial(temp2)
        temp = CM2.StripSpecial(text)
        temp = string.gsub(temp, "%]%[", " ")
        temp = string.gsub(temp, "[^a-zA-Z0-9%s]", "")
        words = CM2.GetWords(temp)
        words2 = CM2.GetWords(temp:lower())

        for word = 1, #words do
            -- Cant be the player name or it locks up the client... Go figure...
            if words[word] ~= UnitName("player") and words[word] ~= plainPlayerName then
                --print(words[word]:lower())
                if CM2_Nick[words[word]:lower()] ~= nil then
                    --{level, class, guild, realm, name} Nick Layout. Name is the unfiltered name.
                    local newWord = CM2.ColorName(CM2_Nick[words[word]:lower()][2], words[word]:lower())

                    word2find = words[word]
                    pos = temp2:find(word2find) or temp:find(words2[word])

                    if newWord ~= nil then
                        --replace with find code.
                        text = CM2.far(text, word2find, newWord)
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
```

Function CM2.far:

```
    function CM2.far(str, fstr, rstr)
    if (str and type(str) == "string") and (fstr and type(fstr) == "string") and (rstr and type(rstr) == "string") then
        --And space at the end so gfind will find till the end.
        --In case a match is there.
        str = str .. " "
        local pos = nil
        for x in str:gmatch("[^%:]"..case_insensitive_pattern(fstr).."[^%:]") do

            if pos ~= nil and pos ~= str:find("[^%:]"..case_insensitive_pattern(fstr).."[^%:]", pos+1) then
                str = str:sub(1, pos) .. rstr .. str:sub(pos + #fstr + 1)
                --print(str)
                pos = str:find("[^%:]"..case_insensitive_pattern(fstr).."[^%:]", pos+1)
            elseif pos == nil then
                pos = str:find("[^%:]"..case_insensitive_pattern(fstr).."[^%:]")
                str = str:sub(1, pos) .. rstr .. str:sub(pos + #fstr + 1)
                pos = str:find("[^%:]"..case_insensitive_pattern(fstr).."[^%:]", pos+1)
                --print(str)
            end
        end
        str = str:sub(1, #str - 1)
        return str
    end
end
```

Function CM2.StripSpecial:

```
    function CM2.StripSpecial(msg, player)
    PlayerStripped = 0

    --Strips out all special characters such as Ö and the like.
    --Should only be used for being returned to a temp string unless replacement is required.
    if msg ~= nil and type(msg) == "string" then
        for x=1, #msg do
            local CharVal = string.byte(string.sub(msg,x,x+1), -1)
            --local StrTab = {}
            --for a=1, #msg do
              --  StrTab:Insert(
            --print("Debug: "..string.byte(string.sub(msg,x,x+1)))
            --print(CharVal)
            if CharVal ~= nil then
                if 146 <= CharVal and CharVal <= 150 then
                    msg = StringReplace(msg, x, "O")
                    if player then
                        PlayerStripped = PlayerStripped + 1
                    end
                elseif 178 <= CharVal and CharVal <= 182 then
                    msg = StringReplace(msg, x, "o")
                    if player then
                        PlayerStripped = PlayerStripped + 1
                    end
                elseif 128 <= CharVal and CharVal <= 134 then
                    msg = StringReplace(msg, x, "A")
                    if player then
                        PlayerStripped = PlayerStripped + 1
                    end
                elseif 160 <= CharVal and CharVal <= 166 then
                    msg = StringReplace(msg, x, "a")
                    if player then
                        PlayerStripped = PlayerStripped + 1
                    end
                elseif 136 <= CharVal and CharVal <= 139 then
                    msg = StringReplace(msg, x, "E")
                    if player then
                        PlayerStripped = PlayerStripped + 1
                    end
                elseif 168 <= CharVal and CharVal <= 171 then
                    msg = StringReplace(msg, x, "e")
                    if player then
                        PlayerStripped = PlayerStripped + 1
                    end
                elseif 153 <= CharVal and CharVal <= 156 then
                    msg = StringReplace(msg, x, "U")
                    if player then
                        PlayerStripped = PlayerStripped + 1
                    end
                elseif 185 <= CharVal and CharVal <= 188 then
                    msg = StringReplace(msg, x, "u")
                    if player then
                        PlayerStripped = PlayerStripped + 1
                    end
                elseif 140 <= CharVal and CharVal <= 143 then
                    msg = StringReplace(msg, x, "I")
                    if player then
                        PlayerStripped = PlayerStripped + 1
                    end
                elseif 172 <= CharVal and CharVal <= 175 then
                    msg = StringReplace(msg, x, "i")
                    if player then
                        PlayerStripped = PlayerStripped + 1
                    end
                elseif 135 == CharVal then
                    msg = StringReplace(msg, x, "C")
                    if player then
                        PlayerStripped = PlayerStripped + 1
                    end
                elseif 167 == CharVal then
                    msg = StringReplace(msg, x, "c")
                    if player then
                        PlayerStripped = PlayerStripped + 1
                    end
                elseif 144 == CharVal then
                    msg = StringReplace(msg, x, "D")
                    if player then
                        PlayerStripped = PlayerStripped + 1
                    end
                elseif 176 == CharVal then
                    msg = StringReplace(msg, x, "o")
                    if player then
                        PlayerStripped = PlayerStripped + 1
                    end
                elseif 152 == CharVal then
                    msg = StringReplace(msg, x, "O")
                    if player then
                        PlayerStripped = PlayerStripped + 1
                    end
                elseif 184 == CharVal then
                    msg = StringReplace(msg, x, "o")
                    if player then
                        PlayerStripped = PlayerStripped + 1
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end

    return msg
end
```

Function CM2.GetWords:

```
    function CM2.GetWords(str)
    if type(str) == "string" then
        local results = {}

        for word in string.gmatch(str, "%S+", 9) do
            table.insert(results, word)
        end

        return results
    end
end
```

Function case_insensitive_pattern:

```
    function case_insensitive_pattern(pattern)

  -- find an optional '%' (group 1) followed by any character (group 2)
  local p = pattern:gsub("(%%?)(.)", function(percent, letter)
    --print(percent, letter)
    if percent ~= "" or (not letter:match("%a")) then
      if letter ~= "-" then
          -- if the '%' matched, or `letter` is not a letter, return "as is"
          return percent .. letter
      elseif letter == "-" then
          return "%-"
      end
    else
        if letter == "[" then
          return "%["
        elseif letter == "]" then
          --print("hi")
          return "%]"
        end
      -- else, return a case-insensitive character class of the matched letter
      return string.format("[%s%s]", letter:lower(), letter:upper())
    end

  end)

  return p
end
```

Function CM2.ColorName:

```
    function CM2.ColorName(str, word)
    --Using the class and word provided precolor it for chat.
    if str == "MONK" then
        word = "\124cff00ff96" .. CM2_Nick[word][5] .. "|r"
    elseif str == "DEATH KNIGHT" then
        word = "\124cffc41f3b" .. CM2_Nick[word][5] .. "|r"
    elseif str == "DRUID" then
        word = "\124cffff7d0a" .. CM2_Nick[word][5] .. "|r"
    elseif str == "HUNTER" then
        word = "\124cffabd473" .. CM2_Nick[word][5] .. "|r"
    elseif str == "MAGE" then
        word = "\124cff69ccf0" .. CM2_Nick[word][5] .. "|r"
    elseif str == "PALADIN" then
        word = "\124cfff58cba" .. CM2_Nick[word][5] .. "|r"
    elseif str == "PRIEST" then
        word = "\124cffffffff" .. CM2_Nick[word][5] .. "|r"
    elseif str == "ROGUE" then
        word = "\124cfffff569" .. CM2_Nick[word][5] .. "|r"
    elseif str == "SHAMAN" then
        word = "\124cff0070de" .. CM2_Nick[word][5] .. "|r"
    elseif str == "WARLOCK" then
        word = "\124cff9482c9" .. CM2_Nick[word][5] .. "|r"
    elseif str == "WARRIOR" then
        word = "\124cffc79c6e" .. CM2_Nick[word][5] .. "|r"
    end

    return word
end
```

Edit 1: Managed to fix self name warning but noticed that saying your full matching player name in chat is not being colored. I can deal with this myself. No changes we able to be made yet to fix the other players saying the players name warning yet.

Comment: I kinda have an idea that might work but until I can test it I would still like to see if someone can help me better here. Thanks again in advance.

Comment: I think it will help if you come up with a much shorter example. You'll get more readers to try it and it may help *you* to find the answer.

Comment: I cant... That is literally the whole code used and sub functions required to parse the name being said and notify and then the code to color based on class. I am attempting to strip down the name warning code to use gsub but so far is still incorrectly triggers on the player saying his own name.